# python selenium webdrive con un svg

Tags: html, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

tengo un objeto SVG,Estoy usado webdriver selenium como hago para que presione el svg que cierra la venta

html

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 14 14"><path d="M 14,1.41 12.59,0 7,5.59 1.41,0 0,1.41 5.59,7 0,12.59 1.41,14 7,8.41 12.59,14 14,12.59 8.41,7 Z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: intentaste hacer `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('svg')` ?

Comment: ya lo intente pero no hace nada

Comment: y si haces un `print(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('svg'))` cuantos registros te muestra?